# how do I change the color for a tree node icon in a primeNg tree?

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, primeng

I am using primeNg tree in an angular CLI 6 project.

```
"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
"primeng": "6.0.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
```

What I need to do is to change some of the treeNode icon colors. I need to have a blue checked sign...

I am using the styleClass parameter and setting the color: blue and the icon AND the text is shown as blue.

How do I just change the icon color.

```
                {
                    label: 'Procedure is an isolated CABG Surgery',
                    icon: 'fa fa-folder',
                    // collapsedIcon: 'fa fa-folder',
                    // expandedIcon: 'fa fa-folder-open',
                    styleClass: 'xxx',
                },
```

and in css file, I have

```
.xxx {
color: blue;
```

}

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

what I ended up doing was

```
icon: 'fa fa-check',
```

I added

```
.fa-check:before {
    color: green;
}
```

and all is well...

Comment: just in case for your deleted post > for the p-tree> How to make first node bold. Here is the answer . `:host::ng-deep  {
  .parenttree {
     tbody tr td:first-child .ui-treenode-label {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
}` Add a styleClass called `parenttree' in your HTML <p-tree> tag.

Answer (score 1):

just add the below in your CSS:

```
::ng-deep .ui-tree-container .ui-tree-toggler{
color: #f9c71a;


}


::ng-deep .ui-tree-container .ui-treenode-icon{
    color: #f9c71a;
  }

  ::ng-deep .fa-caret-right::before {
     content: "\F067";
  }

  ::ng-deep .fa-caret-down::before {
     content: "\F068";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

as is mentioned in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75848739/11389517)

try to use css directly on your JSON tree